# How to fetch the following data into the tableview using Swift?

Tags: swift, alamofire

First lets see the json data.

```
[
{
"id": "244",
"name": "PIZZAS",
"image": "",
"coupon": "1",
"icon": "",
"order": "1",
"aname": "",
"options": "2",
"subcategory": [
  {
    "id": "515",
    "name": "MARGARITA",
    "description": "Cheese and Tomato",
    "image": "",
    "icon": "",
    "coupon": "1",
    "order": "1",
    "aname": "",
    "options": "2",
    "item": [
      {
        "id": "1749",
        "name": "9 Inch Thin & Crispy Margarita",
        "description": "",
        "price": "3.40",
        "coupon": "1",
        "image": "",
        "options": "2",
        "order": "1",
        "addon": "495",
        "aname": "",
        "icon": ""
      }]
  }]
}]
```

I have used Alamofire and getting response through this code below:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl, parameters:nil , encoding: .JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseString { response in
                print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
            }
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")


                if let jsonResult = response as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {
                    let Name = jsonResult[0]["name"]
                    let ID = jsonResult[0]["id"]
                    let Order = jsonResult[0]["order"]

                    print("JSON:    Name: \(Name)")
                    print("JSON:  ID: \(ID)")
                    print("JSON: Order: \(Order)")

                }
            }
```

But after getting response data I am not able to get any value. Here I want to fetch all data like name,id and subcategory - how to implement this?

Comment: If I need to save all names into an array so that i can use it to display in tableview. How can I do this. @MAB

Comment: You have accepted an answer to your question. Don't change the meaning of your question now. If you have new issues, *post a new question,* don't deface this one.

Comment: ok sure. I thought problem is within same criteria.@EricD

Comment: You can *refer* to this Q&A in your new question - but it has to be a new question: this one has been resolved and shouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one problem there.
First response is of type `Response<Anyobject, NSError>`, it's not the parsed object you're looking for, instead you should use `response.result.value` as you did for the log.
Second even if you tried to cast `response.result.value` to `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>` it will not pass because in your json data you have ann inner array `subcategory` which cannot be casted to `Dictionary<String, String>`

This code should work for you:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl, parameters:nil , encoding: .JSON)
    .validate()
    .responseString { response in
        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
    }
    .responseJSON { response in
        print("Response JSON: \(response.result.value)")


        let array = response.result.value as! Array<NSDictionary>
        for item in array
        {
            let Name = item["name"]
            let ID = item["id"]
            let Order = item["order"]
            let Subcategories = item["subcategory"] as! Array<NSDictionary>
            for subCategory in Subcategories
            {
                let subId = subCategory["id"]
            }

        }
}
```

And here is the results in the playground: [image]

Cheers.

Comment: I'de recommend using https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator for generating a swift model for your data, it's and easy and quick way to parse your data directly to objects.

Comment: Here in my app i am doing without creating model classe. I have not much idea to retrieve data into data models. If u can please  explain or send link regarding this

Comment: I saw about JSon Accelerator which is available on App store. but it only can able to change into objective C , java and others but not in swift

Comment: take a look at this tuto : http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/10/how-to-use-alamofire-and-swiftyjson-with-swift-swift-2-ios-9-xcode-7/

Comment: i mean link about how to create class model by using SwiftyJsonAccelerator

Comment: I wan to fetch all the names in an array so that  i can display it in tableview cell. But I can't able to do it. If you have any idea please help me